# how to Launch Cordova app when phone locked

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on an android app built on apache cordova. The app used to send your location via SMS, Email & in app notification to your predefined contacts. I want this sharing event to be triggered on double tapping on screen (when locked) or 3-4 times pressing the power button/ volume button.

Its for emergency situation, when user may not be able to unlock phone & open app to share any info.

I've searched a lot but could not find any relevant info. is there any available plugin to do that? I know very little of JAVA. **Expecting any plugin that would allow me to launch the app(any activity) when phone is locked.**

Any helpful information or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this kind of task, you need to run a service in background, it is not possible to use any cordova webview, so you won't be able to run any javascript.

I don't think there is any plugin doing such a thing as it is very specialized.

I needed to create an app that needed to send notification to the user depending on his location. It ended up in writing a native plugin...

So the best advice I can give you is "It's never too late to learn Java" ;-)

maybe some other JS framework (maybe [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)) allows such things but I never used it yet so it might be impossible too.